# Does it make sense to include the classifier in scikit-learn's Pipeline for cross-validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Let's assume that I have the typical training and test dataset setup (`X_train`, `y_train`, `X_test`, `y_test`) and a very simple pipeline which I want to use in cross validation (I would have multiple more complex pipes, but this is just a simplified example)

When I am doing the cross validation as shown in the code below, I am wondering if the `Pipeline` approach would actually work.

**My question is, does the `Pipeline` call the `.predict()` method on the last "test"-fold, or does is call the `.predict()` on the fold that was used for training?**

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),           
    ('classification', GaussianNB())   
    ])

cv = KFold(n=X_train.shape[0], n_folds=10)

scores = cross_val_score(pipe, X_train, y_train, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy')
```

Or maybe an even simpler example:

Comment: If `cross_val_score` would call `predict` on the training folds, then it would be utterly useless. What makes you think it would?

Comment: I don't know actually, had some weird results and was a little bit worried. But it was another issue ... you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `cross_val_score` will always predict on the `test` part indicated by `cv` (take a look at `[(train, test) for train, test in cv]`). If `cv` separates `train` and `test` such that they are disjoint (the case with e.g. `KFold` or other cross validation split objects), then the fitted estimator/pipeline will always predict on *held out* data.

See [this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.15.X/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L1240)